# How to override magento core model (model class file direct under app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model directory)

Tags: php, magento, model, overriding

I want to override an core model class, but I cannot find the correct way to do it.

I have googled a lot, but some of the examples are shown how to override a model which are not located at `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model` folder and some of the examples are shown how to override a model which in the sub-dir of `Core` dir, like `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resources/Eav/Mysql4/`.

I have read the examples, but I still cannot find a way to override it. For example, I want to override `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php`

And here is the xml I use, but it is not working. Please help me to find out which part is wrong. Thanks in advance!

`app/etc/models/My_Core`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Core>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </My_Core>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/My/Core/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </My_Core>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_core_store>
                <rewrite>
                    <class>My_Core_Model_Store</class>
                </rewrite>
            </my_core_store>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

The new Store.php file is at `app/code/local/My/Core/Model/Store.php`. And the magento version is 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your config.xml has some mistakes. Follow in this way..

```
< ?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <my_core>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </my_core>
    </modules>
    <global>
       <models>
          <core>
              <rewrite>
                  <store>My_Core_Model_Store</Store>
              </rewrite>
          </core>
       </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

and also in the model class, You need to extend the Parent Class Name. For Ex: `My_Core_Model_Filename extends Mage_Core_Model_Store`

Comment: OK, now I know why I am wrong. I didn't extends the parent class. So when we customise the Model, we actually "extend" it, not "override" it.

Answer (score 2):

For most of them it will be

`<modulename>
<rewrite><path_to_file>My_Extension_Path_To_Extended_File</path_to_file>
</modulename>`

So in your case it would be

`<core>
<rewrite><store>My_Core_Model_Store</store></rewrite>
</core>`

Although, note that for Mysql4 or Resource files, they are defined under `modulename_mysql4`or `modulename_resource`.

Comment: Hi Fran, I have changed the `config.xml` according to  your solution, and I got a 404 page. And I checked the PHP error log, nothing is recorded.